# MySQL- How to select rows which matches any value from an array

Tags: mysql

How to select rows from a table where its condition can match any value from an array.

something like this:

```
Select * from Table Where Name = Array_of_Names;
```

Array_of_Names is a java array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass it using `IN` keyword in query with multiple items separated by `comma` in brackets like :

```
String query = "Select * from Table Where Name IN (";

for(int i =0 ;i<arrayName.length();i++){
  query = query + "'" +arrayName(i) + "'" + ",";
}

query = query.substring(0, query.length()-1);
query = query + ")";

// execute your query here
```

This ll pass your query like :

```
Select * from Table Where Name IN ('arrayvalue1','arrayvalue2','arrayvalue3');
```

as per length of array.

Comment: For me the last sentence worked for PostgreSQL too : `Select * from Table Where Name IN ('arrayvalue1','arrayvalue2','arrayvalue3');
`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to craft the SQL statement and use WHERE ... IN ...

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

Comment: I think that OP want a solution for a generic array.

Comment: while the array is fixed here, you can pass the array as a variable instead to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

here you are:

```
Select * from Table Where Name in ("Tom", "Dick", "Harry");
```